# Javascript Test file returning undefined values

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined-behavior

I have to make a Javascript version of the LET language and im making a test file. But each time i call a function its coming back undefined. There's an AST file, an interpreter file and finally my test file. There's also an Environment file but my test file for that works just fine.

Can any of you guys help me out and tell me why its returning undefined?

This is the test file for the AST.js/Interp.js files

```js
var main = function(){

//console.log(valueOf(AST.DiffExp(5,3)))
var env1=Env.Env(null,null,null)
var env1=Env.extendEnv(env1, "x", 250);
console.log(AST.ConstExp(8))


}


//var modules = require('./modules.js');
var ConstExp = require('./Interp.js', './AST.js');
var AST=require('./AST.js', './Interp.js')
var valueOf=require('./Interp.js')
var Env= require("./Environment.js")
if(require.main === module) {
main();
}
```

This is the AST.js file

```js
function ConstExp(i)  {
    this.Int = i;
}
function VarExp(id) {
    this.Id  = id;
}
function IsZeroExp (exp) {
    this.Exp = exp;
}
function DiffExp (exp1, exp2) {
    this.Exp1 = exp1;
    this.Exp2 = exp2;
}
function IfExp (cond, cons, alt)  {
    this.Exp1 = cond; //Condition
    this.Exp2 = cons; //Consequent
    this.Exp3 = alt;  //Alternative
}
//id is a strng not an expression
function LetExp (id, val, inExp) {
    this.Id = id;
    this.Exp1 = val
    this.Exp2 = inExp
}

module.exports = {
    ConstExp : ConstExp,
    VarExp : VarExp,
    IsZeroExp : IsZeroExp,
    DiffExp : DiffExp,
    IfExp : IfExp,
    LetExp : LetExp
}
```

this is the Interpreter file (Interp.js)

```js
function valueOf (e, p) {
    switch(e.constructor){
        case AST.ConstExp: 
                return Number(e.Int);
                break;
        case AST.VarExp:
                return ENV.applyEnv(p, e.Id);
                break;
        case AST.IsZeroExp:
                return valueOf(e.Exp, p) == 0;
                break;
        case AST.DiffExp: 
                return valueOf(e.Exp1, p) - valueOf(e.Exp2, p);
                break;
        case AST.LetExp:
                var body = e.Exp2;
                var v = valueOf(e.Exp1, p);
                var pp = ENV.extendEnv(p, e.Id, v);
                return valueOf(body, pp);
                break;
        case AST.IfExp: 
                if (valueOf(e.Exp1, p) == true){
                    return valueOf(e.Exp2, p);
                } else {
                    return valueOf(e.Exp3, p);
                }
                break;
    }
}
module.exports = {
    valueOf: valueOf
}
AST = require("./AST.js");
ENV = require("./Environment.js");
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from the functions, so the return value is (as you said) undefined.

Comment: I noticed the functions in the AST file dont return anything but in the Interpreter file, the cases return values. I'm just sort of confused bc I didn't write this code haha but thanks, I'll just edit the functions so they return values